# ASP.NET application, long delay in IIS in AuthenticateRequest

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We have a http module that measures how long server requests spend in individual states. In one of our servers we see requests take a large amount of time in the AuthenticateRequest state - seconds, sometimes even minutes.

This is Windows 2008, IIS 7, Integrated pipeline, .NET 3.5 ASP.NET application

We do not use any authentication. "Anonymous authentication" is the only one enabled.

Any suggestion where to look at would be very appreciated.

Comment: I would start with the HttpModule you are using to log the AuthenticateRequest state.  If it is logging to a database, then there could be something blocking the inserts on the database side at certain times.  Is it logging to a database? If so what DBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)?

Comment: The thing is we do not do any authentication on this level. It looks like something else (IIS? ASP.NET engine?) is doing something ...

Comment: Even if you aren't doing any authentication, the http module is somehow tracking at least the time that the AuthenticateRequest step takes, so I would think it is worth looking into. You could also look into request tracing in IIS and dig into the details for requests that your httpmodule show as taking longer than expected. Note that request tracing does have some overhead and possible performance impact.